# InnoDB on server with 2 SSDs

Tags: mysql, ssd, innodb

I have a server with 2 SSDs. I'm running a LAMP install and have an innoDB database on it.

my questions are :

1) would innoDB automatically use both SSDs or would it only use one ?
2) would I incur a significant performance hit if I use a 2 HDD instead of the 2 SSDs ?

thanks

Comment: How are the drives configured?  InnoDB doesn't know about the storage devices under its files, it just cares about the files; if you put the storage somewhere where it's using both SSDs, then it will.  Please clarify exactly how your system is set up, and what you're looking to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> would innoDB automatically use both SSDs or would it only use one ?

No, InnoDB (and MySQL) knows nothing about your storage subsystem. You need to configure the storage devices as needed (RAID, LVM, filesystems, etc.), mount the storage in a location of your choosing, and then instruct MySQL to use it.

> would I incur a significant performance hit if I use a 2 HDD instead
>   of the 2 SSDs ?

This completely depends on your workload and the capabilities of your block devices. If you have old or cheap SSDs but 15k Fibre Channel hard drives, well, those hard disks will walk all over your SSDs.

Spinning hard drives tend to do better with sequential workloads whereas SSDs tend to perform better with random IO.

Comment: thsnks, What should I do to make it use both SSDs as one ?

Comment: Use mdadm to create a RAID1 mirror pair, then mount that volume somewhere and mount it somewhere that MySQL can use it. If you need assistance doing either of those things, post them as separate questions, but search the site before posting, as both topics have likely been covered several times here already.

Comment: keep in mind that a mdraid raid1 will destroy your IOPS rate. It's fine if you habe sequential reads and writes, but it's very slow in random I/O.

Answer (score 1):

You can make InnoDB use two or more separate devices without using RAId or something, you just need to specify multiple files in your innodb_data_file_path variable

Something like:

innodb_data_file_path = /ssd1/ibdata1:1024M;/ssd2/ibdata2:1024M;/ssd1/ibdata3:1024M;/ssd2/ibdata4:128M:autoextend

will put the first GB of data from your database on the first SSD, then the 2nd on the other, etc.

It is probably best to use the 'innodb_file_per_table' which makes a separate innodb file for each table, then you can just symlink different tables or databases to different drives, to load balance is however you think will give you the best performance where you need it.

There are both advantages and disadvantages to doing it this way. The best solution for speed is to have enough ram to keep all of the innodb data cached in memory as well.